# How can we make a compromise between Tomcat and Websphere?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, websphere

Our team is facing a difficuties while developing/modifying a servlet.
The servlet is having some unknown problem and we think I may due to too many request.

We would like to find a way so that the request could be queue up.
But what matter most is that we are developing the servlet using tomcat as the servlet container, when we put it in the production server, our company use websphere to hold it.

I don't know about websphere, but I am sure it have some way to control the requests. But we are only allowed to use tomcat to develop. Thus we do not know what would happen in the production server, this make us very sad. Of course, our company cannot afford to make another websphere for development usage.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't find the information you're looking for in the [Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp), you should probably test/debug on WAS. There is a [free developer license](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/index.html) for Windows and Linux (you must install it on your development machine - [see the FAQ for restrictions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/faq-wasdevelopers.html)).

While there's some merit in targeting Tomcat in development, a complete ban on the target application server is counterproductive. Production is not the place you want to find incompatibilities.

Comment: What are the constraint of this free lisence WAS?

Comment: This question is in the FAQ: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/faq-wasdevelopers.html See _What exactly is the entitlement provided with the no-charge WebSphere Application Server for Developers?"_

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat and Websphere has different architecture and servlet engines and i think you cannot get guarantee that application that perfectly runs on Tomcat will be as well on Websphere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JBoss free version for tests. It much more similar to Websphere than a Tomcat.
We use it for this purpose on one of the project - and it cover 99% of our problems with  deploys. 
Also if i remember it right exist development license version of websphere and it kind of free(but with mad license restrictions)

Comment: really? Are their architectures similar? Do I need to use a specific version of JBOSS to compromise the existing websphere ( I think I is websphere 5 )?

Comment: at least JBoss is real application server (and tomcat is just web container)

Comment: we use it for test - and actually it help us a lot. don't sure on 100% that it helps you (  -  we mostly solve deploy problems

Comment: but i think better way is to use free development WS